# XML uppercase element values in Java

Tags: java, xml, uppercase

I have a ByteArrayOutputStream that looks like this:

```
<GENERAL>
        <City>Barcelona</City>
        <PostalCode>3061</PostalCode>   
</GENERAL>
```

Is there a fast way in java to conert that to the following:

```
<GENERAL>
            <CITY>Barcelona</CITY>
            <POSTALCODE>3061</POSTALCODE>   
  </GENERAL>
```

Uppercase only inside the tags.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple text replacement should suffice in most cases.

```
Path path = Paths.get("general.xml");
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
String xml = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

xml = Pattern.compile("(</?[-\\w]+)")
    .matcher(xml)
    .replaceAll(mr -> mr.group().toUpperCase());

data = xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Files.write(path, data);
```

For java 8 and older that do not possess that version of replaceAll:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(</?[-\\w]+)")
    .matcher(xml);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group().toUpperCase());
}
m.appendTail(sb);
xml = sb.toString();
```